# web.config file sharing among multiple user and prevent overriding

Tags: web-config

If in a asp.net projects,  10 people are working how to share web.config file among all the 10 people also how to prevent overriding of web.config by many people simultaneously.

Comment: What source control system are you using?  What is your deployment mechanism?  These are the control points for sharing and controlling change.

Comment: thanks for your reply.